# How to authenticate to a custom web service with oauth2 and swift

Tags: swift, web-services, oauth

I have to retrieve some data from a custom web service, before the web service let me download the json I have to authenticate to it.
My question is how can I handle the authentication?
I mean can you please pass me some code to understand the whole process?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's an in-depth topic, and here's a really thorough tutorial that walks you through the steps:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/177597/oauth-2-0-swift-tutorial

It's definitely not something you want to write yourself, here are two popular open source libraries (covered in that tutorial) that are useful for this:

https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift

https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-ios-oauth2

Comment: Thanks but I’ve already red that tutorial, my problem is that I don’t have to connect to google but to a custom webservice and I don’t know how to do it. I don’t have to open a login controller but I have to authenticate to a custom webservice. Thanks!